# Static data member initialization order

Tags: c++

Consider the code below in a single translation unit:

```
class C {
private:

    struct Init {

        Init() {
            /* compute data once here */
        }
    };
    static const Init& i;
    static int data[];
public:
    /* interface for reading data */
};

const C::Init& C::i = Init();
int C::data[200];
```

1. Is C::i always initialized after C::data no matter the order of the definition of both?
2. Is this solution the most elegant one for computing static data once?

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit on what you think the answers are to the questions you've proposed?

Comment: 1. I think yes because of the types involved. data is int[], while i is const Init&, which maybe involves a more elaborate construction before main() but after other static data members of "basic" (POD?) types. I need a confirmation from the  standard and the right terminology involved in the two types of objects.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`int C::data[200]` is *zero-initialized*, which means that it is *statically initialized*. Static initialization comes before dynamic initialization. Since `C::Init::Init()` is not a constant expression, `C::i` is dynamically initialized, necessarily *after* `C::data`.

See 3.6.2 for details.

A bootleg quote:

> Variables with static storage duration [...] shall be zero-initialized before any other initialization takes place. [...] Together, zero-initialization and constant initialization are called static initialization; all other initialization is dynamic initialization. Static initialization shall be performed before any dynamic initialization takes place.

Comment: Good thing that people like you exist here :) +1

Comment: It's worth noting that the order of static initialization is not defined, and neither need it be - all initial values of statically initialized variables are already known at compile time, so the order of their initialization cannot have any observable effects.

Answer (score 0):

`C::data` isn't initialized there, so order doesn't matter.

The shorter solution is to use static function and dummy variable:

```
class C {
private:

    static void Init() {
        /* compute data once here */
    }

    static bool data_init_helper;
    static int data[];
public:
    /* interface for reading data */
};

bool C::data_init_helper = (C::Init(), false);
int C::data[200];
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is C::i always initialized after C::data no matter the order of the
>   definition of both?

The order is guaranteed if they are defined in the same compilation
unit, otherwise not.

> Is this solution the most elegant one for computing static data once?

No. If you really have to have it static, then a better way (and to prevent a possible static initialization order fiasco) is to do it like this :

```
struct someDataStr
{
  int data[200];
};
someDataStr& AccessData()
{
  static someDataStr *ptr = NULL;
  if ( NULL == ptr )
  {
    ptr = new someDataStr;
    // initialize value
  }
  return *ptr;
}
```

If it doesn't have to be static, then use dependency injection, and pass the object containing data to all classes using it.